# If table cell equals variable value

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I've found plenty of help for deleting a row if a cell equals a number specified in the code, but I'm having trouble deleting a table row if the value of a cell equals the value of a variable.

*(This is my first ever attempt at VBA and first ever use of a site like this to seek help on any subject.  I appreciate any help you can lend.)*

```
Sub NeverGonnaWork

Dim x as String

x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value

Dim tbl as ListObject

Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

'if column 15 in last row of the table equals x, delete that row of the table'

If Cells(tbl.ListRows.Count, (15)) = x then
tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your current code?

Comment: That code works for me.  I did finally get it to error out, but only after I deleted all the rows first.  If your table no longer has any rows and you are trying to delete a row then that could be causing it.  if that is the case you can just add an if statement to check if the row count is greater than 0 `tbl.ListRows.Count <> 0`

Comment: I'd make sure to add the worksheet you expect the `Cells(tbl.ListRows.Count, (15))` to be on, e.g. `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tbl.ListRows.Count, (15))`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It *"doesn't work"*, because you are referencing `Worksheet.Cells(<amount of rows in table>, 15)` rather than the actual cell position inside the table.

In other words, you're just referencing some *"random"* cell in your [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) `Worksheet`.

*Change your code to this and it should work ;-)*

```
Private Sub thisWillWork()

  Dim compVal as String: compVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value2
  Dim tbl as ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2")

  If tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Range(,15) = compVal Then
     tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Delete
  End If

End Sub
```